# Getting Error with ./src in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I've got the following code in WebStorm 9 that I believe is valid (ecma6)

```
'use strict';

import codeCampBase from './src';

export default codeCampBase;
```

The error is on ./src saying "can not resolve ./src yet /src is a valid directory and the program works correctly.

Comment: hmm... Is it really a valid syntax? Can you point me to the appropriate place in spec? traceur compiler throws EISDIR error on attempt to use a directory as module specifier. Babel doesn't throw error, but resultant code can't be run because module can't be loaded. What am I missing?

Comment: The code is being run through babelify and so Browserify is implementing the directory semantics